# Created by field showing service account when adding item to SharePoint by PowerApps

Tags: powerapp

I am trying to add item to SharePoint using Canvas app but columns created by/Modified by fields are showing the service account instead of user who has opened the App.

In SharePoint list column Created By/Modified by fields should show the actual user name who submitted the form instead of service account.

On submit button of PowerApps , Patch function is called.

Comment: Try to test with a user not owner or co-owner of the app. I think your `service account` is the user you use to create the app?

Comment: Thank you Jleture, somehow my account was using service account connections. I have now removed and all good. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Great! I now post the message as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue when you try to test your application with the owner or co-owner account. With a *real* user account, it should be fine: SharePoint `created by` column will be the expected identity.